# What does it mean when experiment produces a cube root function for the relation between period and length of a torsional pendulum?

Tags: waves, differential-geometry, harmonic-oscillator

I conducted an experiment that investigated the relationship between the period of the torsion pendulum and its length. A graph of the data collected revealed a cubic root correlation as opposed to the theoretical square root function expected. **How am I supposed to interpret that ?** A graph of the result is presented below.

[image]

Also when the period squared is graphed against length L for the above data, a linear regression model can be produced with high R^(2) but as expected a y-intercept is also produced instead of the theoretically predicted proportionality. **Is the y-intercept connected in anyway to the fact that the power function above is not a square root ?**

May be it could help I will add the data collected here :
[image]

Not sure if this helps but I will say it anyways:The pendulum was rotated 10π rads initially which could be big enough to skew the motion from being SHM but not sure to what extent.

Comment: Fitted parameters without error bars are meaningless. What are the uncertainties?

Comment: @Rococo I added the data collected to the question.

Comment: Okay, but presumably you fit this to a function like $a*x^b$. Each of those fitted parameters has some uncertainty. For example, if you fit for $b$ is $0.363\pm0.2$ then you are actually consistent with a square root and there is nothing to explain. If the error bars are smaller then there might be a true disagreement, and you should think about any sources of systematic error in your measurement.

Comment: @Rococo How can I find the uncertainty in b however? Plus, when I graph period squared vs length, the uncertainty in the y-intercept for the linear regression model does not include 0, meaning that at the very best the value of b here is less than 0.5 ?

Comment: Since $T \propto l^2$, I would plot that as ordinate and abscissa and try to figure where it deviates from linear, an then try to figure out what that means. (E.g. is it too slow when it is short, or too fast when it gets longer and so on).